# Does a "word" have multiple meanings, or are there multiple "words"?

Tags: terminology

I always find it difficult to discuss the meaning of a word because I don't really have a definite meaning of *word* in my head.

*Cook* refers to the verb (to cook) but it can also refer to the noun (a cook). Would you say *cook* is one word with multiple meanings or that the verb and the noun are separate words? Is a word simply the arrangement of the letters?

Comment: Guess what? Dictionary makers take different positions on this. There are clear cases of both, and an enormous body of cases that fall between them. It's your language; you decide. As long as the right sounds come out, nobody cares whether you think _bear_ and _bare_ are the same word, just like nobody cares whether you think the verb _bear_ has some relationship with the noun _bear_. Most people think that _pulley_ and _pull_ are related, for instance.

Comment: It's a good question, and there's no good answer.

Comment: This is a deeply philosophical question about the ontology of words. Many (if not most) syntacticians prefer to call words *lexical items* and use syntactic category (among other things) to individuate them. Thus, *cook* (qua noun) is taken to be a distinct lexical item from *cook* qua verb. Drastically different (and unrelated) meaning is also a criterion for distinctness; for example, *bank* (qua riverside) is taken to be a distinct lexical item from *bank* (qua financial institution).

Comment: of possible interest is [Dixon and Aikhenvald's](http://assets.cambridge.org/97805218/18995/excerpt/9780521818995_excerpt.pdf) volume on the topic

Answer (score 3):

Where a word has the same form for both the verb and the noun, a dictionary will normally give separate entries for each, or, at least, differentiate between them in a single entry.

Verbs and nouns themselves usually have different forms, but these are not entered separately in a dictionary. You don’t look up the plural noun *cooks*. You look up the singular *cook*. 
You don’t look up the past tense of the verb *cooked*. You look up the basic form *cook*.

The form of a word you look up in a dictionary is called  a **lexeme** (also known as a **lemma**). The word as it occurs in a text, or the word that a word processing program counts, is called an **orthographic word** (or a **token**).

Answer (score 2):

This is a deeply philosophical question about the ontology of words. Specifically, it is a question about the individuation conditions of words. This question, sadly, has no answer given that we use the word "word" very inconsistently (see below).

Many syntacticians prefer to talk about *lexical items* rather than words, given the nebulousness of the concept *word*. Lexical items (on at least one use of the term) are individuated by syntactic category (among other things).

Thus, *cook* (qua noun) is taken to be a distinct lexical item from *cook* (qua verb).

Drastically different (and etymologically unrelated) meaning is also a criterion for distinctness of lexical items. For example, *bank* (qua riverside) is taken to be a distinct lexical item from *bank* (qua financial institution), since these two uses have radically different meanings and etymologies.

The problem with discussing the individuation conditions of words themselves is that English speakers' use of the word "word" is very inconsistent. In different contexts, we use the word "word" to pick out different things, with different individuation conditions. Sometimes we use "word" to refer to phonic-graphic *types* (that is, general arrangements of sounds and/or letters), sometimes to *tokens* (that is, particular utterances or inscriptions of these types), sometimes to phonic-graphic types *plus* meanings, sometimes to phonic-graphic types *plus* meanings *and* syntactic categories, and so on. This context-sensitivity of the word "word" is discussed by at least a few of the philosophers who have thought about the ontology of words.

---

If you are interested in pursuing the (relatively small) literature on the ontology/metaphysics of words, here are a few good papers:

Alward, Peter. “Between the Lines of Age: Reflections on the Metaphysics of Words.” *Pacific Philosophical Quarterly* 86 (2005): 172-187.

Bromberger, Sylvan. “What Are Words? Comments on Kaplan (1990), on Hawthorne and Lepore, and on the Issue.” *Journal of Philosophy* 108, no. 9 (2011): 486-503.

Cappelen, Herman. “Intentions in Words.” *Nous* 33, no. 1 (1999): 92-102.

Hawthorne, John and Ernest Lepore. “On Words.” *Journal of Philosophy* 108, no. 9 (2011): 447-485.

Kaplan, David. “Words.” *Proceedings of the Aristotelian Society*, Supplementary Volumes 64 (1990): 93-119.

Kaplan, David. “Words on Words.” *Journal of Philosophy* 108, no. 9 (2011): 504-529.

McCulloch, Gregory. “Making Sense of Words.” *Analysis* 51, no. 2 (1991): 73-79.

Stainton, Robert. “Meaning and Reference: Some Chomskyan Themes.” In *The Oxford Handbook of Philosophy of Language*, edited by E. Lepore and B. C. Smith. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2006.

Wetzel, Linda. "On Types and Words." *Journal of Philosophical Research* 27 (2002):239-265.

Wetzel, Linda. *Types and Tokens: On Abstract Objects*. Cambridge, MA: The MIT Press (2009)

Answer (score 1):

Taking an extreme position in answer to this question, it could even be argued as I think Arimasa Mori does argue regarding the Japanese language and I think is implied by a side of Derrida's view of language, that each an every utterance of a word is a word with meaning which never exists separately to the social and environmental context in which the word is uttered.

Mori argued that in Japanese every utterance of the word "I" the first person singular, was embedded in language of politeness and humility such that, contra the first person in French and other European languages, it was not accompanied by any third person perspective (super-addressee, Bakhtin; aucoustic cap, Freud; Other, Lacan; Generalised Other, Mead) linguistic or intra-psychic, such that the meaning of "I" in Japanese is no more no less than "you for you."

Derrida I think that implies, even while being critical, that while the meaning of words, the philosophy of presence (or co-presence, something else that accompanies words) is a cultural fantasy it is an inevitable or essential one. Husserl's irreal meanings too have an element of fictionality to them, while at the same time they are essential. Perhaps for Husserl meanings are fictions that we must believe in to understand words.

Comment: Some links to the sources you cite would be helpful.

Comment: The Mori source is given here in Japanese https://www.flickr.com/photos/nihonbunka/15885099604/

Answer (score 0):

To a first approximation, dictionary listings are normally classified by

**(A)** word (different homonyms, such as [bear1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Bear) (to carry etc) and bear2 (the animal)

**(B)** different intercategorial polysemes, such as

bank1

noun ...

verb ...

**(C)** different polysemes (senses)

bank1

noun

1. A piled-up mass, as of snow or clouds. See Synonyms at heap.
2. A steep natural incline.
3. An artificial embankment.
   ...         [AHDEL]